# Count Array element with specific string value

Tags: php

I have this output:

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "url": "https:1783.json",
        "id": 1783,        
        "created_at": "2019-08-29T13:52:47Z",
        "status": "open",
        "recipient": null,
    },
    {
        "url": "https:1781.json",
        "id": 1781,
        "created_at": "2019-08-29T10:21:57Z",
        "status": "open",
        "recipient": null,            
    },
    etc...
```

All I want to do is count the number of elements with the **status** of **open**

> "status": "open",

This is whatI have so far:

```
$result = json_decode($result, true);
echo count(array_keys($result, "open"));
```

But it outputs **0**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this two ways, fixing the current idea would mean having to extract the `status` column from the `results` element of the data and then using `array_keys()`, as currently the arrays it's looking at are at the wrong level...

```
echo count(array_keys(array_column($result['results'], 'status'), "open"));
```

Which is short, but also involves processing the whole array a few times.

Alternatively a simple `foreach()` loop just counting each time it's the value your after...

```
$count = 0;
foreach ( $result['results'] as $res )  {
    if ( $res['status'] == 'open' ) {
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
```

This (IMHO) is faster and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) with [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) like below,

```
echo count(array_filter($arr['results'], function ($val) {return $val['status'] == 'open';}));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/WIUuS)

**Output**

```
2
```

> Note: Your json is invalid.